# Indentation with python code

Tags: python, indentation

i was actually adding a loop in my code and an error of " inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation " with the line of " while ind<3242:"

So if you can help me, here is the code :

```
        ind=0
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    xtemp=[]   
    for i in x:
        r=open('DataSets/Corpus/'+i,'r')
        text=r.read()
        fin=text.split('^')
        for j in fin:
            while ind<3242:
                Y.append(str(i))
                xtemp.append(j)
                ind=ind+1
        r.close()
```

I checked the number of spaces and indentation and it looks the same actually.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well there is an obvious indentation error in the first line of your code. If you're posting a question specifically about indentation, you really need to reproduce your indentation accurately.

Comment: If anything `for i in x` is an error itself because `x` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

> I checked the number of spaces and indentation and it looks the same

You need to check that you either always use spaces, or always use tabs. A tab may look like four spaces, but it isn't.